# uninitialized constant User::relationship using @blog.user.followers.build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-models

The below code works without error:

```
  = form_for @blog.comments.build, :remote => true do |f|
```

However the below results in the error "uninitialized constant User::relationship":

```
  = form_for @blog.user.followers.build do |f|
```

User model is declared as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :comments

  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id",
                                   :class_name  => "relationship",
                                   :dependent   => :destroy

  has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
  has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
end
```

Why does the first example work but not hte second?

EDIT:
Blog model:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

end
```

Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed, :class_name => "User"

  validates :follower_id, :presence => true
  validates :followed_id, :presence => true

  validate :validate_followers

  def validate_followers
    errors.add(:follower_id, "You cannot follow yourself") if follower_id == followed_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please show your Blog model? Does a blog has only one user?

Comment: Is this "has_many :blogs" instead of "has_many :users"?

Comment: @timbrandes yes each blog has only one user

Comment: @BenB thx, fixed. same error though.

Comment: If you change the `:class_name` option on reverse relationships to `=> 'Relationship' do you still get the problem? It should be the correct case for a class name I believe.

Comment: @Shadwell, put that as an answer so it can be marked.

Comment: @BenB good point - done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the `:class_name` option on reverse relationships to:

```
:class_name => 'Relationship'
```

do you still get the problem? It should be the correct case for a class name I believe.

Comment: In my case it was writing `:class_name => 'Relationships'` instead of `:class_name => 'Relationship'`